# when i enter a video name to the input variable the vidplayer() function doesn't look for it but plays a random video on youtube

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to build a gui interface where i can enter the title of a video and once i click on the button, the selenium function (vidplayer) will look for the video  on youtube and play the first one of the result page.
Everything works fine except when i click on the button the selenium function plays the first video on my youtube HOMEPAGE instead of looking for the one i chose earlier

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from tkinter import *
    root=Tk()
    root.title('Youtube Video Player')
    text=Label(root,text="In order to save time and avoid procrastination.\nEnter the name of the video 
    you have in mind,and by the power of the gods it will play")
    text.pack()
    input=Entry()
    input.pack()
    a=str(input.get())
    #playing the video with the 'a' variable title on youtube
    def vidplayer():
        browser=webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Downloads\\chromedriver')
        browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+a)
        video=browser.find_element_by_id('video-title')
        video.click()
    button=Button(text="Play Video", command=vidplayer)
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? For example, have you examined the url you are passing into `browser.get` to see if it is what you are assuming it is?

Comment: yes, the url is correct and i tried adding the video title variable (a) as an argument for the vidplayer() function, but it says the function need one more argument

Comment: Are you _certain_ it's correct? I don't see that that is possible. You're defining `a` by calling `input.get()` about a millisecond after you create the entry widget, well before the user has a chance to type anything.

Comment: So do i have to add something in between?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `a.get()` about a millisecond after creating the entry widget, well before the user has a chance to enter anything.

The fix is simple: get the value when you actually need it, and not before:

```
def vidplayer():
    query = input.get()
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+query
    browser=webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Downloads\\chromedriver')
    browser.get(url)
    ...
```